# Getting counts of membership in combination of groups using sparklyr or dplyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, pyspark, dplyr, sparklyr

I have a spark dataframe I'm manipulating using sparklyr that looks like the following:

```
input_data <- data.frame(id = c(10,10,10,20,20,30,30,40,40,40,50,60,70, 80,80,80,100,100,110,110,120,120,120,130,140,150,160,170), 
           date = c("2021-01-01","2021-01-02","2021-01-03","2021-01-01","2021-01-02","2021-01-01","2021-01-02","2021-01-02","2021-01-01","2021-01-02","2021-01-01","2021-01-02","2021-01-05","2021-01-01","2021-01-02","2021-01-03","2021-01-01","2021-01-02","2021-01-01","2021-01-02","2021-01-02","2021-01-01","2021-01-02","2021-01-01","2021-01-02","2021-01-05","2021-01-01","2021-01-05"), 
           group = c("A", "B", "C", "B", "C", "A", "C", "A", "A", "A", "C", "A","B","A", "B", "C", "B", "C", "A", "C", "A", "A", "A", "C", "A", "A", "B","A"), 
           event = c(1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0))
```

[image]

I'd like to aggregate the data such that I have a count of the number of "events" (where `event == 1` ) and "non_events" (where `event == 0`) for each combination such that the final output looks like the following:

```
data.frame(group_a = c(1,0,0,1,0,1), 
           group_b = c(0,1,0,1,1,0), 
           group_c = c(0,0,1,0,1,1), 
           event_occured = c(3,1,2,0,2,2), 
           event_not_occured = c(4,2,2,0,2,2))
```

[image]

So, for example, there were no combinations where A and B were groups for the same ID so that gets a 0 for `event` and `non_event`. There were 4 IDs in which group A was involved in, of which 3 resulted in an `event` and 1 resulted in a `non_event`, so on and so forth.

What approach using sparklyr (or dplyr or pyspark) would allow for aggregation as described above? I tried the following but I'm getting the exact same number of `event` as `event_not_occurred` so I must be doing something wrong but can't pinpoint it:

```
combo_path_sdf <- input_data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  mutate(order_seq = ifelse(event > 0, 1, NA)) %>%
  mutate(order_seq = lag(cumsum(ifelse(is.na(order_seq), 0, order_seq)))) %>%
  mutate(order_seq = ifelse((row_number() == 1) & (event > 0), -1, ifelse(row_number() == 1, 0, order_seq))) %>% 
  ungroup()

    combo_path_sdf %>%
      group_by(id, order_seq) %>%
      summarize(group_a = max(ifelse(group_a == "A", 1, 0)),
                group_b = max(ifelse(group_b == "B", 1, 0)),
                group_c = max(ifelse(group_c == "C", 1, 0)),
                events = sum(event)) %>%
      group_by(order_seq, group_a, group_b, group_c) %>% 
      summarize(event = sum(events),
                total_sequences = n()) %>%
      mutate(event_not_occured = total_sequences - event)
```

Final output in the following format would be ok too:

```
data.frame(group_a = c("A", "B", "C", "A,B", "B,C", "A,C"), 
           event_occured = c(3,1,2,1,2,2), 
           event_not_occured = c(4,2,2,1,2,2))
```

(image below for A,B is incorrect, should be 1,1 not 0,0)
[image]

Comment: Does your data shown and the expected output match? Why is group_a for `A, B` 0 for both event types? In your data there are events `A` and `B` for ID 10.

Comment: Oh that's an error, you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following matches your requested output format, and process the data in the way I understand you want, but (as per the comment by @Martin Gal) does not match the example result you provided.

```r
input_data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(group_a = max(ifelse(group == 'A', 1, 0)),
            group_b = max(ifelse(group == 'B', 1, 0)),
            group_c = max(ifelse(group == 'C', 1, 0)),
            event_occured = sum(ifelse(event == 1, 1, 0)),
            event_not_occured = sum(ifelse(event == 0, 1, 0)),
            .groups = "drop") %>%
  group_by(group_a, group_b, group_c) %>%
  summarise(event_occured = sum(event_occured),
            event_not_occured = sum(event_not_occured),
            .groups = "drop")
```

This idea is a two step summary process. The first summarise creates an indicator for group from each event and counts the number of events/non-events. The second summarise, combines all similar groups.

Regarding the code you are using that produces the same number of events and non-events. Take a look at `hts_combined`. This is not defined in the code you have shared and hence your script might be reading a variable from elsewhere.